# Java BorderLayout not resizing/centering correctly?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, border-layout

I know there's something really simple here that I'm doing wrong but I just can't see it.  I've tried searching online and checking other answers but I can't find someone having the same issue.

I'm trying to create a JFrame with a panel of buttons in NORTH and a panel of buttons in SOUTH and let the user load an image to go in CENTER.  When the user resizes the JFrame I'd like the image in the center to stay centered horizontally and vertically but the image is only staying centered horizontally.  I'm using a JLabel to hold the image.  Can you please help point me in the right direction?

```
theJFrame.setResizable(true);

imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(theImage));
imagePanel.add(imageLabel);
theJFrame.add(imagePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

theJFrame.pack();
```

EDIT:
The user Hovercraft Full of Eels posted a solution that worked which has since been deleted so I can't choose it, but they suggested setting imageLabel to have a GridBagLayout.  I made that change and now it stays centered vertically and horizontally.

EDIT:
I'm having a hard time paring down my code enough for a SSCCE because I have another class that creates and calls the GUI class to run it, but I can give you a more detailed code example:

```
    theJFrame = new JFrame();
    theFilterButtonPanel = new JPanel();
    theUtilityButtonPanel = new JPanel();
    imageLabel = new JLabel();

    theJFrame.setResizable(true);
    theJFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Create and add filter buttons
    for (final Filter f : MY_FILTERS) {
        createFilterButton(f.getDescription());
    }

    theJFrame.add(theFilterButtonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    myUtilityButtonPanel.add(createCloseButton());
    theJFrame.add(theUtilityButtonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    theJFrame.add(imageLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

When I do it like this, just adding the imageLabel straight into the JFrame, it puts it on the far left of the window and, if I resize it, it stays vertically centered.  If instead I use

```
    JPanel theImagePanel = new JPanel();
    theImagePanel.add(imageLabel);
    theJFrame.add(theImagePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

then it centers it horizontally but it stays at the top of the screen when the window is resized (does not center it vertically).

Comment: @lyric, hovercraft deleted the answer because there is no need to create a panel just to add a label to the panel. If you add other component to the panel in addition to the label then yes, that is the solution. Otherwise the solution I gave you will work. If it doesn't you have something wrong with your code and you should figure out way it doesn't work instead of complicating your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Add the JLabel directly to the frame. There is no need to add the image to a panel first.

The default alignment for an image only JLabel is to be centered vertically and horizontally in the space available.

Comment: When I do that it doesn't stay centered either horizontally or vertically.  I also tried adding empty JPanels to East and West in addition to having imageJPanel at center.  This causes it to stay centered vertically when the frame resized instead of horizontally, but still can't find a way to make it stay centered both horizontally and vertically.

Comment: @Lyrric, it works fine for me. Post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html). Download the example code and replace the button in the CENTER with a JLabel containing an ImageIcon.